# React Hook Form with ZodResolver not enabling save button and preventing form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, react-hook-form, zod

I'm currently working on a React application where I'm using React Hook Form along with Zod for form validation. However, I've encountered an issue where the Save button in my form is always disabled, and the form is not getting submitted when using zodResolver with priceSchema, but it works fine when I remove zodResolver.

PriceForm.jsx:-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { z } from 'zod'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const priceSchema = z.object({
    price: z.number().positive().int()
})

const PriceForm = ({ course, courseId, fetchData }) => {
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const form = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(priceSchema),
        defaultValues: course
    }, []);

    const { handleSubmit, reset } = form;
    const { isSubmitting, isValid } = form.formState;

    const onSubmit = async (values) => {
        try {
            setIsEditing(false);
            await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/instructor/courses/${courseId}`, {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(values)
            });
            fetchData();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='mt-6 border bg-slate-200 rounded-md p-4'>
            <div className='font-medium flex items-center justify-between'>
                <p className='text-zinc-600 py-2'>Course Price</p>

                {isEditing ? <div className='flex gap-x-2'>
                    <button
                        className='px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 text-white rounded-md'
                        onClick={() => {
                            setIsEditing(false)
                            reset(course)
                        }}>
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type='submit'
                        disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting}
                        onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                        className='px-4 py-2 bg-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-700 text-white rounded-md'>
                        Save
                    </button>
                </div> : <button onClick={() => {
                    setIsEditing(true)
                }}>
                     Edit
                </button>}
            </div>

            {isEditing ? <form
                className='mt-2'
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            >
                <input
                    className='p-1 shadow-lg appearance-none rounded w-full outline-none'
                    type="number"
                    id='price'
                    placeholder="Enter course selling price..."
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    defaultValue={course.price}
                    {...form.register('price')}
                />
            </form> : <p className='text-md font-semibold mt-2 py-1'>
                {course.price || 0}
            </p>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PriceForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input comes as string to the form, so add `coerce` between the priceSchema as:-

```
const priceSchema = z.object({
    price: z.coerce.number().positive().int()
});
```